# Spring MVC AngularJS handle image upload

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have an application using Spring MVC for back-end and AngularJS for front-end.

**Problem:**

I have a multi-step form there on one of the steps user uploading an image.

For now, this i use this algorithm:

On form, there is a button to choose an image. once image is selected it is sent to /upload_image controller and uploaded into the temp folder. Then, once the user submit a final request, the image moved from img_temp to images/*created_item_id*

But it also creating much complications with image moving because i also have some additional manual approval for the form data in some cases.

**Question:**

Do i do it in the right way? Maybe there is some methods to do so without temporal image creation?

Comment: If use FormData API can send everything at one time using `$http`. Will require custom config but should be easy to research how

Comment: what FormData API ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: You could try using a directive for this https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload....we implemented this for our app which is on spring and angular

Comment: Use this module: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Comment: ye i use. It. There is no problem with files upload itself. The prob is in the prcess that i have to create 'temp' files